# VBA macro function to sum across a selected range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to implement a function that will calculate the present value of an annuity conditional on life expectancy and sex. The annuity data in Sheet1 looks like this:

| Age | Sex | Annual payment (start of each year) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | F | 2000 |
| 98 | F | 16000 |
| 91 | M | 1800 |
| 100 | M | 1950 |

The life table in Sheet2 is structured as follows:

| Age | Female | Male |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 000 | 100 000 |
| 1 | 99 009 | 98 996 |
| 2 | 98 034 | 98 007 |
| 3 | 97 073 | 97 034 |
| 4 | 96 128 | 96 077 |
| 5 | 95 200 | 95 137 |
| 6 | 94 289 | 94 214 |
| 7 | 93 396 | 93 309 |
| 8 | 92 521 | 92 423 |
| 9 | 91 664 | 91 556 |
| 10 | 90 826 | 90 707 |
| 11 | 90 007 | 89 879 |
| 12 | 89 208 | 89 070 |
| 13 | 88 428 | 88 281 |
| 14 | 87 668 | 87 512 |
| 15 | 86 928 | 86 763 |
| 16 | 86 208 | 86 034 |
| 17 | 85 508 | 85 326 |
| 18 | 84 828 | 84 638 |
| 19 | 84 167 | 83 971 |
| 20 | 83 527 | 83 323 |
| 21 | 82 906 | 82 696 |
| 22 | 82 305 | 82 088 |
| 23 | 81 723 | 81 499 |
| 24 | 81 160 | 80 930 |
| 25 | 80 616 | 80 380 |
| 26 | 80 090 | 79 849 |
| 27 | 79 582 | 79 336 |
| 28 | 79 092 | 78 841 |
| 29 | 78 620 | 78 363 |
| 30 | 78 164 | 77 903 |
| 31 | 77 724 | 77 459 |
| 32 | 77 301 | 77 031 |
| 33 | 76 892 | 76 619 |
| 34 | 76 499 | 76 221 |
| 35 | 76 120 | 75 838 |
| 36 | 75 754 | 75 469 |
| 37 | 75 401 | 75 113 |
| 38 | 75 061 | 74 770 |
| 39 | 74 733 | 74 438 |
| 40 | 74 416 | 74 118 |
| 41 | 74 109 | 73 808 |
| 42 | 73 812 | 73 509 |
| 43 | 73 524 | 73 218 |
| 44 | 73 244 | 72 936 |
| 45 | 72 972 | 72 661 |
| 46 | 72 707 | 72 394 |
| 47 | 72 448 | 72 132 |
| 48 | 72 195 | 69 905 |
| 49 | 71 946 | 67 778 |
| 50 | 71 701 | 65 742 |
| 51 | 71 459 | 63 786 |
| 52 | 71 220 | 61 901 |
| 53 | 70 982 | 60 079 |
| 54 | 70 746 | 58 312 |
| 55 | 70 509 | 56 593 |
| 56 | 70 272 | 54 916 |
| 57 | 70 035 | 53 275 |
| 58 | 69 795 | 51 666 |
| 59 | 69 553 | 50 084 |
| 60 | 67 099 | 48 525 |
| 61 | 64 688 | 46 987 |
| 62 | 62 315 | 45 466 |
| 63 | 59 976 | 43 960 |
| 64 | 57 668 | 42 468 |
| 65 | 55 391 | 40 988 |
| 66 | 53 143 | 39 520 |
| 67 | 50 923 | 38 063 |
| 68 | 48 731 | 36 618 |
| 69 | 46 570 | 35 185 |
| 70 | 44 439 | 33 764 |
| 71 | 42 341 | 32 358 |
| 72 | 40 278 | 30 966 |
| 73 | 38 252 | 29 592 |
| 74 | 36 265 | 28 236 |
| 75 | 34 322 | 26 901 |
| 76 | 32 424 | 25 589 |
| 77 | 30 575 | 24 301 |
| 78 | 28 777 | 23 040 |
| 79 | 27 033 | 21 808 |
| 80 | 25 346 | 20 607 |
| 81 | 23 718 | 19 440 |
| 82 | 22 152 | 18 306 |
| 83 | 20 648 | 17 210 |
| 84 | 19 208 | 16 151 |
| 85 | 17 834 | 15 131 |
| 86 | 16 526 | 14 152 |
| 87 | 15 284 | 13 214 |
| 88 | 14 109 | 9 404 |
| 89 | 13 000 | 6 631 |
| 90 | 9 867 | 4 634 |
| 91 | 7 441 | 3 210 |
| 92 | 5 576 | 2 204 |
| 93 | 4 152 | 1 500 |
| 94 | 3 073 | 1 013 |
| 95 | 2 261 | 678 |
| 96 | 1 654 | 527 |
| 97 | 1 204 | 407 |
| 98 | 872 | 314 |
| 99 | 628 | 241 |
| 100 | 451 | 184 |
| 101 | 322 | 140 |
| 102 | 229 | 107 |
| 103 | 163 | 81 |
| 104 | 115 | 61 |
| 105 | 81 | 46 |
| 106 | 57 | 35 |
| 107 | 40 | 26 |
| 108 | 28 | 20 |
| 109 | 20 | 15 |
| 110 | 0 | 0 |

For each person from Sheet1 I need to use their age and sex data to find the number of living people l_x, then sum to calculate the present value of the annuity:

[image: Present Value]

where omega is the maximum ag in the life table equal to 110 and i is the interest rate which I pass to the function.

In my code so far I try to find the cell with the appropriate l_x but the function throws  a #VALUE error on call:

```
    'x is the age, ipa is the interest rate, sex is sex, R is the annual payment
Function A_pre(x As Integer, ipa As Double, sex As String, Optional R As Double) As Range

Dim cell As Range
Dim lline As Range
'the life table range and the l_x (range and value)
Dim lx As Range
Dim l0R As Range
Dim l0 As Integer

'present value annuity
Dim atot As Double
atot = 0


'choose the range based on sex
If sex = "F" Then
lx = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A,B:B")
Else
lx = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A,C:C")
End If

Set l0R = lx.Find(x)
'Set l0 =

'discount appropriate payments

'For Each lline In lx.Rows
'If lline.Columns(1) >= x Then
'atot = atot + 


End Function
```

A function call like this:

```
=A_pre(x = 88; sex = "F"; ipa = 0,02)
```

results in a #VALUE error.

What am I doing wrong and how do I implement the function in question? I want to arrive at a function that returns the present value of the annuity for a given set of input parameters.

Comment: You have to add to the function name the return value. Sg. like this `Set A_pre = l0R` but this returns only the x value if found.

Comment: @Blackcat I added this line before 'End Function' but the error persists. Could you clarify where exactly to add 'Set A_pre = l0R'?

Comment: You added it correctly. You need also to add `Set` to `lx` because they are ranges. Like this `Set lx = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A,B:B")` in both lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the equation in this code:

```
Function annuity(x As Integer, ipa As Double, sex As String, Optional R as Double = 1) As Double


Set datasheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
If sex = "F" Then col = 1 Else col = 2
Set rangex0 = datasheet.Columns("A:A").Find(x)

For k = 0 To 110 - x
  annu = annu + rangex0.Offset(k, col) / (rangex0.Offset(0, col) * (1 + ipa) ^ k)
Next k
annuity = annu * R
End Function
```

Add getting omega value programatically

```
Function annuity(x As Integer, ipa As Double, sex As String) As Double


Set datasheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")         'edited to Sheet2
If sex = "F" Then col = 1 Else col = 2
Set rangex0 = datasheet.Columns("A:A").Find(x)
omega = datasheet.Columns(1).End(xlDown)
For k = 0 To omega - x
  annu = annu + rangex0.Offset(k, col) / (rangex0.Offset(0, col) * (1 + ipa) ^ k)
Next k
annuity = annu
End Function
```

Comment: That is really super. Is there a way to read that $\omega$ from Sheet2 instead of hard-coding the numeric value of 110?

Comment: @honkhonk Pls. find the improved version

Comment: For some reason, I get #VALUE error with your imorpved code. I have tried to declare omega as a Double but the error is still there.

Comment: @honkhonk Is there any empty cell in column A before the table? (e.g. A1)? If yes this can cause error. I test it on Sheet7 but you need Sheet2. sorry

Comment: There are indeed blank cells, so that explains the error. I will handle the rest, thank you!